# How to hide all the div elements below a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide all the div comes below a particular div. Actually i have hosted my dummy site through a free hosting provider site and they are showing their site information below my page. The information is inside a div but no id or class is applied. So I want to hide all the div comes after my particular div. How can i achieve this?

the site structure is like below:-

```
form body
<br>
my site content
<br> 
my empty div
<br>
their div with their site content.
```

I have given id to my empty div and want to hide all the div comes below my empty div.
Thanks

Comment: This probably violates the free hosting provider's Terms of Service.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Is it worth answering this question or not?

Comment: If answering this is not right, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @azeós there's no rule against answering questions that may voilate someone's ToS, other than SO's ToS of course..

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with Robert Harvey and I'd suggest you not do this, I'd still share a snippet for some learning experience.

```js
var selectedDiv = document.getElementById('_id_of_element');

while (selectedDiv.nextElementSibling) {
  var sibling = selectedDiv.nextElementSibling;
  sibling.parentNode.removeChild(sibling);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with CSS. But that's probably against their TOS.

```css
#yourDiv ~ div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="yourDiv">
  Your content
</div>
<div>
  Hosting content 1
</div>
<div>
  Hosting content 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add follows scripts to hide all divs after your specific div -

```
$( "my-empty-div-id" ).nextAll("div").hide();
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22981204)